# Cakephp form never validates when it should

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

Ok, so I have validation somewhat working. It doesn't validate when it SHOULD, which seems to be the opposite of every problem I can find on google. I've tried copying the exact code from the CakePHP docs, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe someone here can figure it out.

Model:

```
<?php

    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

    class User extends AppModel {

        public $validate = array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
            'full_name' => array(
                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 8),
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        );

    }

?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


    class UsersController extends AppController {

        function login() {
            $this->layout = 'signin';
        }

        function signup() {
            $this->layout = 'signin';

            if($this->request->is('post')) {

                $this->User->set($this->request->data);

                if($this->User->validates())
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Validated!');
                else
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Did not validate!' . print_r($this->User->validationErrors, true) . print_r($this->request->data, true));
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

View:

```
<div class="placeholder text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></div>

<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name', array('placeholder' => 'Your full name', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('placeholder' => 'Enter email', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', array('placeholder' => 'Retype Password', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create Account</button>

        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help in the right direction is appreciated. I've always had issues with validation with CakePHP so I never used it before. Now it's required so I have no choice but to drudge through this until I get it working.

Oh, I should note that the data does go through. Here's the result of the `print_r` function:

> Did not validate!Array ( [full_name] => Array ( [0] => This field
>   cannot be left blank ) [password] => Array ( [0] => This field cannot
>   be left blank ) ) Array ( [User] => Array ( [full_name] => Sean
>   Templeton [email] => sean@`********`.com [password] => `********`
>   [confirm_password] => `********` ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this link. It explains how cakephp validations work.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

**Updated:**

Your fullname validation has 'rule'=> 'alphaNumeric' which does not include spaces. but if you check your data [full_name] => Sean Templeton which has a space in it.

You can set your own messages in the model. I don't think I need to say that.

Comment: I did...didn't you read my post? Not only did I read it, I copied the code from it. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Check the action. I don't see any action set in the form. How does you code call the signup actions?

Comment: CakePHP automatically creates the form with the correct action. To be specific it outputs this: `<form action="/users/signup"  id="UserSignupForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">` I don't want to sound rude, but do you even know much about CakePHP?

Comment: Yah, you are rude but no problem. I have started working on Cake very recently. So don't know much. I accept that. But, I am trying to help you out.

Comment: Your fullname validation has 'rule'=> 'alphaNumeric' which does not include spaces. but if you check your data [full_name] => Sean Templeton which has a space in it. I hope this time I am not wrong.

Comment: In Model you did not mention the messages for validations so cake is displaying default message. In this case validation of full_name has failed, may be others as well.

Comment: Update your answer with that. Looks like you hit the nail. Did not think about alphaNumeric not including spacing. Kudos to you sir, I believe I judged you wrongly. Please accept my apology and my acceptance of an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
function signup() {
     $this->layout = 'signin';
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
         $this->User->create($this->request->data); //"create" instead of "set"
         if ($this->User->validates())
             $this->Session->setFlash('Validated!');
         else
             $this->Session->setFlash('Did not validate!' . print_r($this->User->validationErrors, true) . print_r($this->request->data, true));
        }
    }
}
```